# How to slide multiple divs in the right direction?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> tab-right is the class for the button to be clicked for shifting the
>   content from left to right.dedicated,vps,colocation,rackspace are the
>   ids of the divs.My problem is when I click the tab-right button first
>   the 'dedicated' div is sliding in the right direction which is fine
>   but the div "vps is sliding in the left direction.But I want it to
>   slide in the right direction So, help me..........thnx:)

```
$count=0;
$(".tab-right").click(function() {
$count1=0;  
if($count==4)   
{
    $count=0;
}
$count++;
if($count==1)   
{
$('#dedicated').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700,function(){$('#vps').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700);});
}
if($count==2)
{
$('#vps').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700,function(){$('#colocation').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700);});
}
if($count==3)
{
$('#colocation').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700,function(){$('#rackspace').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700);});
}
if($count==4)
{
$('#rackspace').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700,function(){$('#dedicated').toggle('slide', { direction: 'right' }, 700);});
}
});
```

Comment: paste some more code ..fiddle would be great.

Comment: Set up a example in jsbin.com, jsfiddle.net, or stackoverflow would make it much easier to troubleshoot

Comment: paste your html sturcture..